# remove class when browser loads at width at less than 700px

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove a class on an `<a>`  when some one accesses a website on a device smaller than 700px, the code below works when my browser is greater than 700px and I resize it below 700. but if the browser is already below 700px like a phone the class remains.

Thanks in advance.

```
$(function(){
        $(window).bind("resize",function(){
            console.log($(this).width())
            if($(this).width() <700){
            $('a').removeClass('element')
            }
            else{
            $('a').addClass('element')
            }
        })
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    dothis();
});

$(window).resize(function(e) {
    dothis();
});

function dothis(){

    console.log($(window).width());

    if($(window).width() < 700){
        $('a').removeClass('element');
    } else {
        $('a').addClass('element');
    }
}
```

Run the `dothis()` function on `document ready` too so that it would run on page load.

Comment: Thanks mate, see comment on answer above as your solution is giving the same issue! thanks

Comment: @SuperfastGoose check the changes. run the function `dothis()` on document ready to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the event manually when the page is loaded

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        console.log($(this).width())
        if ($(this).width() < 700) {
            $('a').removeClass('element')
        } else {
            $('a').addClass('element')
        }
    }).resize();//trigger the event manually when the page is loaded
})
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this is working better but it only works if you change orientation after the load... So if you load in portrait it doesn't work but if you change the orientation to landscape it works and Vice Versa (both portrait and landscape are within 700px)